# Sharing local image or video files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I understand the that there are simple ways to share links or social network statuses with WP7's ShareLinkTask and ShareStatusTask or even send sms and email with SendSMSTask and SendEmailTask, but is there a way to share images or video's from the users phone? I have researched but have not found this implemented, but would certainly like to add this feature to my application if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share images or videos using the standard sharing API. You need to do it by yourself.